# Sitemap generating random urls

Tags: sxa, urls, sitemap

I have an issue with the SXA sitemap where its rendering urls don't have an item in the site.

When going the sitemap through {siteurl}/sitemap.xml it is containing records such as the below.
[image]

Looking in the content area part of sitecore we cannot find an item that relates to the url.

I was wondering if there is any way to debug or search for these random urls so I can remove them from the sitemap.

I'm using sitecore 9.0.

Comment: https://www.zurich.ie/sitemap.xml :-) ?

Answer (score 2):

```
bgsi/public/group_scheme/index.jsp
```

Sounds like [Java Server Pages](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jspt.html). Sitecore is based on .Net and doesn't use this page extension. That is why I assume that it could be added by some external sitemap(it is a built-in feature of SXA).

I suggest you check external sitemap settings for your SXA website:

1. Open Settings item under your root SXA website
2. Look for "Search Engine Sitemap" settings
3. Check if you have any `External Sitemaps`

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the current implementation of the `SitemapGenerator` service in `Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.dll`, there is a method GetFullUrl which renders the url in the sitemap

```
    protected virtual string GetFullLink(Item item, SitemapLinkOptions options)
    {
      string itemUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options.UrlOptions);
      return options.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + options.TargetHostname + itemUrl;
    }
```

You can implement your own sitemap generator which will inherit from SXA `SitemapGenerator` service and override just the `GetFullUrl` method.

You should also verify if this isn't an issue in your current SXA version because in the latest version of SXA the method is implemented like this:

```
    protected virtual string GetFullLink(Item item, SitemapLinkOptions options)
    {
      string uriString = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options.UrlOptions);
      if (!uriString.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        uriString = new Uri(uriString).LocalPath;
      return options.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + options.TargetHostname + uriString;
    }
```